# GEE do not import data into array

Tags: python, gis, google-earth-engine

I am having problems importing data from Google Earth Engine to a local array using Python API.

A simplified version of my code:

```
import ee
ee.Initialize()

#Load a collection
TERRA = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MOD09A1").select(['sur_refl_b02', 'sur_refl_b07',"StateQA"])
TERRA = TERRA.filterDate('2003-01-01', '2019-12-31')

#Extract an image
TERRA_list = TERRA.toList(TERRA.size())
Terra_img = ee.Image(TERRA_list.get(1))

#Load as array
Terra_img = Terra.get('sur_refl_b02')
np_arr_b2 = np.array(Terra_img.getInfo())
```

But `np_arr_b2` seems to be empty

Does anybody know what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not far from the goal, at least to a certain extent. There's a limit to how many pixels can be transferred over such a request, namely 262144. Your image, when taken over the whole globe (like you are doing), has 3732480000 - over 10000x too many. Still, you can sample a small area and put in the numpy:

```py
import ee
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ee.Initialize()

#Load a collection
TERRA = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MOD09A1").select(['sur_refl_b02', 'sur_refl_b07',"StateQA"])
TERRA = TERRA.filterDate('2003-01-01', '2019-12-31')

#Extract an image
TERRA_list = TERRA.toList(TERRA.size())
Terra_img = ee.Image(TERRA_list.get(1))
img = Terra_img.select('sur_refl_b02')

sample = img.sampleRectangle()
numpy_array = np.array(sample.get('sur_refl_b02').getInfo())
```

It's an area over Wroclaw, Poland, and looks like this when passed to matplotlib via `imshow`:

[image: satellite image]

What if you really need the whole image? That's where `Export.image.toDrive` comes into play. Here's how you'd download the image to the Google Drive:

```py
bbox = img.getInfo()['properties']['system:footprint']['coordinates']
task = ee.batch.Export.image.toDrive(img, 
    scale=10000,
    description='MOD09A1',
    fileFormat='GeoTIFF',
    region=bbox)
task.start()
```

After the task is completed (which you can monitor also from Python), you can download your image from Drive and access it like any other GeoTIFF (see [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32995/fully-load-raster-into-a-numpy-array) GIS Stack Exchange post).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to download data from earth engine to then use them with numpy. You are doing two things wrong here:

1. You are treating Google Earth Engine as a download service. This is not the purpose of Earth Engine. If you want to download big amounts of data (like in your case a year of Terra Surface Reflectance) you should download them directly from the service providers. The only thing you should download from Earth Engine are the end-results of your analysis which you conducted within Earth Engine.
2. `.getInfo` does not get you the satellite data, it will only get you the metadata of your ImageCollection in the form of a JSON Object. If you want to the actual raster data you would have to export it (which, as said in 1, you shouldn't do for this amount of data).